# How do I fix a "The requested session access is denied" error for Microsoft Remote Desktop?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance running in VirtualBox. Within this VM I have two users, `Admin` and `vagrant` where `vagrant` is non-administrative.

When interacting into the VM via VirtualBox, I am having no issue connecting into either `Administrator` or `vagrant`. But when I use Microsoft Remote Desktop, I can only login to the `Administrator`. As I attempt to login as `vagrant`, I keep getting the following

*The requested session access is denied*

According to [this potential solution](http://2008release2en.blogspot.com/2011/04/rds-host-requested-session-access-is.html), I have to *"Remove the /admin parameter in the remote desktop connection"*. I have no clue on how to go about that.

Any feedback on this is much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Try opening the remote desktop application "fresh". Make sure you are not using a saved shortcut to login with the admin account.
- Make sure vagrant is a member of the windows "remote desktop users" user group. Under user accounts on the target VM.

Comment: There we go! You tickled my UNIX senses, so I added `vagrant` to the `Remote Desktop Users` via `Computer Management > System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users > vagrant` and added that user to the Remote Desktop Users group!

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it really helps, it must be added to the group as you said, as there is also an option to add the rdp privilege to the user alone, but it alone does not seem to work, perhaps would need also some other privileges.